# How to Convert TZInfo identifier to Rails TimeZone name/key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, activesupport, tzinfo

**How do you convert js values received as TZInfo identifiers to Rails TimeZone name/key?**

**FROM: `"America/New_York"` returned from JavaScript TZinfo detection**

**TO: `"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` convention used in Rails TimeZone**

or another example:
`"Pacific/Honolulu"` => converted to => `"Hawaii"`

Both are available in `ActiveSupport::TimeZone < Object` mapping but rails uses the key [i.g.  `"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`] in drop-downs, validation & storing to `Time.use_zone()`.

Based on what I understand of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones` this seems to be important especially incases of DayLights savings time (which rails sounds to handle well) and matching just the offset would not accomplish.  If it is not stored to DB with the rails TimeZone name then validation fails and does not match up properly in the user's profile settings page with the dropdown list of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map`

Goal of this is that the user does not have to select their timezone on signup or are required to change it in their settings after signup.  The browser detects it and passes it to hidden_field on signup.  In the rare occasion they sign up in a place different than their home/work. they can manually override in their account settings later.

Seems to be a common gap when trying to ingest js timezone detection.  This might even become a secondary question of how to pass the returned info from js to rails for conversion and then back to js to store back in the hidden_field of the form?  Hopefully I framed the question properly & admittedly a bit green with rails so there may be a simple solution to this...

Thanks so much for all the help! 
-E

---

ActiveSupport Time.zone Documentation

 http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse

```
MAPPING = {"Eastern Time (US & Canada)" => "America/New_York"
```

Using js packaged gem 'temporal-rails' to detect users timezone: 

 https://github.com/jejacks0n/temporal

User Time_Zone implement as seen: 

 http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised

*Using Devise & Devise-Inevitable

---

#### Sign-Up View Script

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var detected_zone = Temporal.detect();
        console.log(detected_zone);  // returns object
        detected_zone = detected_zone.timezone.name;
        console.log(detected_zone);  // returns "America/New_York"
        $('#user_time_zone').val(detected_zone);  // ! need to convert this to rails TimeZone name !
    });
    </script>
```

#### User Model

```
    validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name)
```

#### User Account Settings Form

```
    <%= f.label :time_zone, label: "Time Zone" %><br />
    <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones %>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Temporal includes the needed logic, but to answer your question:

`Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("America/New_York")`

Edit, I guess my answer is incomplete.  You want to get it from "America/New_York" to "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", correct?  If that's the case this is the best solution I have -- though someone may be able to provide a better one.

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.select {|k, v| v == "America/New_York" }.keys.first`

Comment: You can also use the .key method to access the hash like this: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.key("America/New_York")`

Comment: This doesn't support other TZinfo names though like "America/Vancouver"

Comment: Here's what looks to be a more complete mapping than the built in ActiveSupport::TimeZone one: https://gist.github.com/jpmckinney/767070

Comment: @ifightcrime's link works for most, but some mappings are incorrect, see the comments at the bottom of the github page

Comment: The official Ruby mapping is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb

In my case, I needed it for a javascript app that's using a rails backend, so I needed the list and not the ruby function.

Answer (score 3):

The magic I believe everyone is really after, and solves the problem that @ajbraus raised, is a one-liner that could be one of the strangely hardest things to find discussed anywhere:

```
timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/Vancouver').period_for_utc(Time.now.utc).utc_offset]
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fc2baa6d900 @name="Pacific Time (US & Canada)", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: America/Los_Angeles>>
```

Otherwise, if you try searching through ActiveSupport's entire DB of zones, you get nada:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.find{ |tz| tz.tzinfo == ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo('America/Vancouver') }
 => nil
```

The complexity boils down to the following:

- TZInfo gem is rigorously adhering to the IANA specification of timezones
- Rails' ActiveSupport decided to try and simplify display/usage of zones but isn't an exhaustive DB of zones
- ActiveSupport can look up an appropriate zone if you give it an offset
- TZInfo doesn't give you an offset unless you create a TZInfo::TimezonePeriod in the zone of interest
- Ruby 2.6 is apparently revisiting timezone support to clean this business up

Comment: This is better, but not always accurate. `America/St_Thomas` (Atlantic Standard Time year-round) gets mapped to `Atlantic Time (Canada)`, which observes DST. It needs to go to something like `Puerto Rico` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Best option IMO is in a comment by Jo P to the accepted answer. You can do the lookup like this:

```
irb> ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.key("America/Chicago")
=> "Central Time (US & Canada)"
```

Comment: Sadly this won't produce a valid return for all keys in `TZInfo::Timezone.all_identifiers`