# How to filter time_zone by country in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I am trying to filter and returning only the time zones from a specific country.

At now, i tried the without success:

```
# wrong code - i used Brazil only for tests.

validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name)    
= f.input :time_zone, collection: TZInfo::Timezone.all.find_all{ |z| z.name =~ /Brazil/ }

# Return: [#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Brazil/Acre>, #<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Brazil/DeNoronha>, #<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Brazil/East>, #<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Brazil/West>]
```

It will fail at validation, because the differences TimeZone types, then i tried this conversion [How to convert TZInfo to Rails Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221615/how-to-convert-tzinfo-identifier-to-rails-timezone-name-key) but this doesn't work too, there are differences at MAPPING vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the option with value "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" this string is going to be passed to the model for validation. Your validates_inclusion_of is going to run Enum's .include? method on the collection you pass with :in.

Neither Timezone and Time.zone extend Enum to my knowledge, so they will not return an Enum instance that .include? will return true/false for.

If your select consists of ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, this is what you should be checking the inclusion validator against

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones
```

But as ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones doesn't return strings, one way you could get a common type for comparison is casting the above Enum's contents to strings.

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s)
```

With this, a selected value like "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" should evaluate true, as the following does in console without trouble.

```
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s).include?("(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
=> true
```