# Converting a date string into a time zone specific format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
Rails 5.2.3
```

I have a date:

```
"Apr-03-2013 17:47:00"
```

I have a date zone:

```
"America/Los_Angeles"
```

I am trying to turn it into a string:

```
"Apr-03-2013 17:47:00 Pacific Daylight Time (GMT-07)"
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
time_obj = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["America/Los_Angeles"].parse("2013-04-03 17:47:00")
Time.at(time_obj).strftime("%b-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Which gives me:

```
"Apr-03-2013 17:47:00 PDT"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need custom logic and/or you own database of timezones to get it exactly like that.

Using `%Z` with `strftime` is going to give you what ever your OS likes and there are a few disclaimers in the [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

One idea that you might get some mileage out of: If you are starting with a time zone identifier like "America/Los_Angeles" then you can use ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING to get a friendlier name, or at least a Rails time zone name.

eg:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.key("America/Los_Angeles")
=> "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

But that won't work for every identifier:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.key("America/Detroit")
=> nil
```

You can see which ones will map like this:

```
TZInfo::Country.get('US').zone_identifiers.map {|ident| [ident, ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.key(ident)] }
```

So in that case you need to fall back to the identifier you have, or perhaps [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497349/11162681) might work.

Then you'd need to deal with the daylight savings part, here you can use `dst?`

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["America/Los_Angeles"].parse("2013-04-03 17:47:00").dst?
```

Then you'd need to splice all that together! ... and add the offset as well.

Comment: This is one of things I was considering, but my question is really whether there's existing functionality, to get this done in a less complicated fashion